# math.min and math.max vs sort for efficiently finding values in a list

Tags: vb.net, list, sorting, max, min

In visual basic when trying to find the largest and smallest values in a list is it more efficient to use math.min/max like so:

```
Dim highest As Decimal = Decimal.MinValue
Dim lowest As Decimal = Decimal.MaxValue

For Each item As Decimal In listNumber
    highest = Math.Max(highest, item)
    lowest = Math.Min(lowest, item)
Next
```

or to sort the list and grab the values by index like so:

```
listNumber.Sort()
listNumber(0)
listNumber(99)
```

It looks like using min/max is the preferred method, but they both seem to work well enough for a list of 100 decimal values, is one more efficient than the other or is this just a 6 vs half dozen sort of thing?

I tried to find a way to benchmark this in Visual Studio 2013 Express, but it looks like I would have to upgrade to Visual Studio Ultimate, did I miss something?

Comment: _"I tried to find a way to benchmark this in Visual Studio 2013 Express, but it looks like I would have to upgrade to Visual Studio Ultimate, did I miss something?"_ You just need to use a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` and a meaningful test. But i can tell you that you're micro-optimizing. Use the most readable and maintainable code which is `listNumber.Min()` and `listNumber.Max()`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks that's really helpful in general, but it looks like in this case they're both running at 1ms

Comment: @apaul34208: The compiler may generate similar output for each of these methods. Any differences between your methods and the built-in methods may be realized with a much larger sample size. However you should use built-in methods where possible, as they are much more likely to be optimal for cases like these. You shouldn't try to micro-optimize, unless your use cases justify it somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting the items means that you won't only find out which one is the largest and smallest, you will also arrange all items in between according to value. Although it's simple to do, it's still extra work that you don't have to make the computer do.

You can use the `Min` and `Max` methods to get what you want just as easily as sorting the list:

```
Dim highest As Decimal = listNumber.Min()
Dim lowest As Decimal = listNumber.Max()
```

Comment: @Yunnosch - Soo sorry!!!!  Sometimes I use see the blue button and don't realise it's the "Add Another Answer" button.  Would be great if stack overflow changed the color :p. Ironically the "Add comment: button on the right of this box, is also blue.  Honest mistake :) I have deleted. 

My original comment was this:

guffa - is there any difference between the two with browser compatibility?

Comment: @ReenaVerma: This is VB.NET code, so it's not run in a browser at all.